# Specify a custom PYTHON_EGG_CACHE dir with zc.buildout?

Tags: buildout, python-egg-cache

We're having problems when trying to deploy a number of projects which use zc.buildout - specifically we're finding that they want to put their `PYTHON_EGG_CACHE` directories all over the show. We'd like to somehow set this directory to one at the same level as the built-out project, where `eggs` can be found.

There is some mention online that this can be done for Plone projects, but is it possible to do this without Plone?

Are there some recipes that can set up an environment variable so we can set the `PYTHON_EGG_CACHE` executable files in `./bin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean. Three options that you normally have:

- Buildout, by default, stores the eggs in a directory called `eggs/` inside your buildout directory.
- You can set the `eggs-dir` variable inside your buildout.cfg's `[buildout]` section to some directory. Just tell it where to place them.
- You can also set that very same option in `.buildout/defaults.cfg` inside your home directory.  That way you can set a default for all your projects.  Handy for storing all your eggs in one place: that can save a lot of download time, for instance.

Does one of those (especially the last one) accomplish what you want?

And: don't muck around with eggs in the generated `bin/*` files.  Let buldout pick the eggs, that's its purpose.

Comment: The PYTHON_EGG_CACHE is not the same as the eggs directory. Zipped eggs that require unzipping to get at certain resources, are unzipped in that directory. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192323/what-is-the-python-egg-cache-python-egg-cache

Answer (score 4):

The PYTHON_EGG_CACHE is only used for zipped eggs, your best bet is to have zc.buildout install all required eggs unzipped:

```
[buildout]
...
unzip = true
```

If your system python has zipped eggs installed that still require unzipping for resource access, and setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE in your scripts is your only option (as opposed to setting the environment variable for your user), you could try to use the `initialization` option of zc.recipe.egg to add arbitrary Python code to your scripts:

```
[a-part]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
...
initialization = 
    import os
    os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/tmp/python_eggs'
```

Comment: I think '/tmp/python_eggs' should be wrapped in quotes, so: 
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = '/tmp/python_eggs'

Comment: @seddonym: yes, sorry, this is a section of python code and the string should be quoted.