# PyPI local cache for Jenkins/local builds

Tags: python, django, jenkins, virtualenv, pip

I have a Jenkins instance which builds my project with its attendant [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) packages from [requirements.txt](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html). However, like with [TravisCI](https://travis-ci.org/) builds, building from scratch each time is very time intensive, and means builds take >4-5mins which is much slower than would be ideal.

What I'm looking for is a way to cache downloaded packages locally, so when a build with the same dependencies is started, rather than having to get from PyPI it can just fetch locally, when a change in version occurs, it can fetch the upstream package as it does now.

Is there such a project out there, as Googling this evening hasn't revealed much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

pip supports this out of the box

```
pip install --download-cache=DIR
```

if an existing file is requested, it's read from the cache. This can also be done with an environment variable `PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE`;

Answer (score 0):

You can an egg proxy cache like

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.eggproxy

This acts like a local proxy for all downloaded eggs making Jenkins more robust
e.g. against timeouts which happen very often with PyPI.

Aside from that you can use the PYCACHE feature of setuptools. See

[What is the Python egg cache (PYTHON_EGG_CACHE)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192323/what-is-the-python-egg-cache-python-egg-cache)