# local pypi package depends on python pypi server

Tags: python, pypi, pypiserver

I created my local pypi server `http://localhost:8080/simple`. I uploaded packages `flask-mongoengine` I need for my project, but when `tox` try to do `pip install` that packages dependency for `nose`, it try to download from `pypi.python.org`

```
Collecting flask-mongoengine==0.9.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
  Downloading https://localhost:8080/packages/flask-mongoengine-0.9.2.tar.gz (112kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 26.8MB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/nose/: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!
    Couldn't find index page for 'nose' (maybe misspelled?)
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!
    No local packages or working download links found for nose
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-n57wg0y0/flask-mongoengine/setup.py", line 74, in <module>
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules'
      File "/var/lib/jenkins/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject/.tox/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 315, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject/.tox/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 361, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject/.tox/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 850, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject/.tox/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1122, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject/.tox/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1134, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject/.tox/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 429, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject/.tox/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 659, in easy_install
        raise DistutilsError(msg)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('nose')
```

My `pypi` server has `nose` package, but some how, its not redirected to that.

Tried the first answer, it gives error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject/.tox/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 82, in __init__
    req = Requirement(req)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject/.tox/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 96, in __init__
    requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8]))
pip._vendor.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "'[global]'"

ERROR: InvocationError: '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myproject/.tox/py35/bin/pip install -i http://localhost:8080 --trusted-host localhost:8080 -r requirements.txt'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

specify the default to point at localhost? in `$HOME/.pypirc` :

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    localpypi

[localpypi]
repository: http://localhost:8080/simple
username:<your_localpypi_username>
password:<your_localpypi_passwd>
```

A bit further up in `requirements.txt` something like this might instead work instead of `.pypirc`, or maybe it might be needed in addtion to:

```
# requirements.txt
--index-url http://localhost:8080/simple
--trusted-host localhost:8080
flask-mongoengine
```

And for `$HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf` :

```
[global]
timeout = 1
index-url = http://localhost:8080/simple
trusted-host = localhost:8080
```

ah yeah this too perhaps :

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver#uploading-packages-remotely

also maybe :

```
python setup.py dist upload -r http://localhost:8080/simple
```

If any dependencies are required from pypi then :

- [PyPI local cache for Jenkins/local builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417515/pypi-local-cache-for-jenkins-local-builds)
- [how to create local own pypi repository index without mirror?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052217/how-to-create-local-own-pypi-repository-index-without-mirror)

I get confused with all the places `--index-url` and `--extra-index-url` can get set, but the thought was to set the index-url for pypi, and for pip too?

Comment: Still its same error, I think, `distutils` will be used, when you try to do `dist upload`.

Comment: Thanks @jmunsch, but I dont want to upload. I want to download package. For `dist upload` it works, but `flask-mongoengine` is not my package, my project is depend on that.

Comment: @Nilesh so maybe `--extra-index-url` sory thought it was a completely local pypi server?

Comment: @Nilesh update, so thought about it a bit, maybe try the `[global]` pip.conf stuff, I forgot that requirements.txt and pip.conf use different formats. hope it helps.