# uWSGI env and PYTHON_EGG_CACHE configuration options

Tags: python, uwsgi

I am taking over a python website and find the following lines on the UWSGI server conf :

```
env = PYTHON_EGG_CACHE      = /tmp
env = AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID     = A..............A
env = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = F..............F
env = JXD_APP_SETTINGS      = prod.py
```

My questions are :

1) what does the python_egg_cache mean ?

2) what is the value of "env" after these 4 lines ? Is it 'prod.py' or is it a concatenation of the 4 value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`evn` option exports an [environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) variables to the UWSGI web server process. The option can be specified manyt times to export multiple varibles. The values can be read from `os.environ` dict in Python.

`PYTHON_EGG_CACHE` is not uWSGI specific and it is answered here: [What is the Python egg cache (PYTHON_EGG_CACHE)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192323/what-is-the-python-egg-cache-python-egg-cache) It is most likely related how Python eggs are deployed on your production server.